# Paypal digit goods flow dialog - prevent refresh

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using Paypal digit goods flow to get the integrated payment dialog into my site. When user open the dialog and they clicks cancel, it seems PayPal forces a refresh. Same thing happens when they complete the purchase.

Is there any way to prevent this? I'm also using Google Wallet which does not do this because it's terrible for user experience and I have to worry about preserving the state of the page now.

Comment: I am not sure as i don't use adaptive payment but express checkout. But i think if paypal redirect you on your website then once the query reach the website it's your website which is responsible for this force refresh i think. Once paypal redirect you i don't see how they can force the refresh as they don't handle anything anymore. I don't have this issue with express checkout.

Comment: You use express checkout and this doesnt happen to you??? You mean the paypal dialog that pops up on top of your site (not a new window), and then you click the (x) on that dialog to close it, and it doesnt refresh? I don't know how that's possible, I have no such code that does a refresh, in fact I don't even see any way for the client code to listen for such an event (on close dialog)

Comment: I don't have any popup. I just have a payment button which lead to a page on paypal website showing a description of what i'm selling and from there the user can log into his paypal account or input his credit card (only work for some countries). One he confirmed the payment on paypal, he will be redirected on my website and from there i have a process to check the payment was effective. That's express checkout, no popup... I use it for recurring payment

Comment: oh I see, yes we are using different flow. I'm using "Digital Goods for Express Checkout" flow. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/